# Create a cache for android application

Tags: android, caching

I am developing an android application which aim is to send some datas to the server. However, sometimes there may not have wifi connection, so I would like to ask if it is possible to create a cache to store multiple sets of data, say maybe 3 sets, and then the app will send those datas automatically when a connection is available.

Here is the way I send my datas to server recently:

```
private class GrabURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{
    //ArrayList object for storing the string pairs
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;

    public GrabURL() { 
        //constructor of the class
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
      } 


    protected void onPreExecute(String key, String value) {
        //store the pair of values into the ArrayList 
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(key,value));
        }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Operation being executed in another thread
        try{
            //set up the type of HTTPClient
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            //set up the location of the server
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urls[0]);
            //translate form of pairs to UrlEncodedFormEntity 
            UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,HTTP.UTF_8);
            //set up the entity being sent by post method
            post.setEntity(ent);
            //execute the url and post the values
            //client.execute(post);
            HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post); 
            HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();
            line = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
         } catch (Exception e) {
             //catch the exception
            line = "Can't connect to server";
         }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Value updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To store primitive things, you can simply use **SharedPreferences**, and as soon as network becomes available, you can check if something with a specific key exist in SharedPreferences. If you don' t write the data inside a persistent environment(like SharedPreferences, Sqlite, file inside SD card or internal storage, etc.) closing the application will cause your data to be loss.

Answer (score -1):

I think Cache data is simple, you can store it in memory or store them as files. You can listen the network state change events to be notified when there is a connection available.

Here is the [Sample Code](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/NetworkConnectivityListener.java).

Comment: So I can make use of the sample code to determine whether there exists a connection, and let the program to wait if no connection is persent. Actually, what I want to do is something like whatsapp, so when no internet connection, it will cache the data first, then it can send even I have returned to the main page

Comment: That is a different question actually, you can use Service to listen the network state change event in the sample code. And send the data out when connection is available. The service will run in background even if you return to the Home.

Answer (score -1):

this may be helpful in having abstract caching lib for object+image caching;

[generic-store-for-android >>](https://github.com/wareninja/generic-store-for-android)